# Psycopg2 update not updating the table and also doesn't throw any errors

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to move some data from a table called 'postsig' to 'usersig' in python and here's the code I'm using

```
cur.execute("SELECT userid FROM usersig")
userid = cur.fetchall()
for i in userid:
    print(i[0])
    q = """SELECT mediaid FROM postsig WHERE OWNERID = %s"""
    data = (i[0],)
    cur.execute(q, data)
    mediaids = cur.fetchall()
    mediaids2 = []
    for i in mediaids:
        mediaids2.append(i[0])
    q2 = """UPDATE usersig SET mediaids = %s WHERE userid = %s"""
    data2 = (mediaids2,i[0], )
    cur.execute(q2, data2)
    conn.commit()
    break
```

in this particular piece of code

```
i[0] = 2716168368 

mediaids2 = [1956830874667839346, 1965242936024519648, 1914749430730816263, 1796363135701978130, 1758915034963881429, 1741263757667258253]
```

after I execute there are no errors but also the actual table doesn't get updated. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thankyou!

Comment: From your given code and example IDs, we can't say for certain the actual `userid` that you are trying to match on exist in the `usersig` table. If it doesn't exist, the table will not get updated.

Comment: It does exist! infact I'm picking the 'userid' from the 'usersig' table before running the for loop mentioned in the post. I've edited the post for clarity now

Comment: You have two variables named `i`.  Are you sure you understand which one is in scope where?

Comment: At the very least, edit your code so that you do not use `i` for two different things. I don't know whether that's the problem, but it's confusing enough that I can't be bothered to try to understand what is going on.

Comment: The 'i' was the problem! Well, I'm sorry. I wouldn't have guessed that could be the problem. I was so sure that it wouldn't be, I didn't even think about it. This was a one off thing and I wasn't gonna use this code for any longer than one. Thankyou regardless :)

Comment: By the way, it should be possible to do this in a single UPDATE, something like `UPDATE  usersid SET mediaids = (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(mediaid) FROM postsig WHERE postsig.ownerid = usersig.userid)`. (Untested, may not work). And while we're at it, having that array in the database at all is slightly suspicious, since you can get those ID:s with a join when you need them (though sometimes, this kind of denormalization is motivated).